# map DataFrame index and forward fill nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with integer indexes that are missing some values (i.e. not equally spaced), I want to create a new DataFrame with equally spaced index values and forward fill column values. Below is a simple example:

have

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[0, 2, 4])
    0
0   A
2   B
4   C
```

want to use above and create:

```
    0
0   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
4   C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'`:

```
df = df.reindex(np.arange(0, df.index.max()+1), method='ffill')
```

Or:

```
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1), method='ffill')

print (df)
   0
0  A
1  A
2  B
3  B
4  C
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reindex` and `ffill`:

```
df = df.reindex(range(df.index[0],df.index[-1]+1)).ffill()

print(df)
   0
0  A
1  A
2  B
3  B
4  C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [319]: df.reindex(list(range(df.index.min(),df.index.max()+1))).ffill()
Out[319]: 
   0
0  A
1  A
2  B
3  B
4  C
```